# Imageview from gallery: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture

Tags: android, bitmap, image-gallery

I am trying to load image from gallery to imageview but it is not working. When I select any image from my phone gallery. It gives

> Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
     //   imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent galeri_int = new Intent();
                galeri_int.setType("image/*");
                galeri_int.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galeri_int.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);


                startActivityForResult(galeri_int,44);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
      //  super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if(bitmap != null){
            bitmap.recycle();
        }

        InputStream stream = null;

        try {
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="gc.uploaderimager.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc"
        android:id="@+id/imageview"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageview"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Resize the bitmap while loading from the inputstream.

Comment: How to resize bitmap? And can It cause lost pixel? lost quality?

Comment: Of course you loose pixels and  quality. But you will not see it as the screen of your device has not that many pixels. For code google options.justDecodeBounds=true;.

Comment: `stream.close();`. That should not be needed as BitmapFactory would already have done that. While the stream is already closed i would expect an IOException.

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream,null,options);

It is not giving error but it is not working also.

Comment: When I select any image imageview is null(white)

Comment: Yes decodeStream() will return null if justDecodeBounds is true. As it will just decode the bounds (wxh) in options. You should google for complete code. Code has been posted here so often.